# Is a backend, and an API the same? And what is a backend web API?

Tags: api, backend

I've tried to google some answers, but I didn't get any clear ones. So going into more detail - What are the differences between a backend, and an API? What is a backend web API even?

I know an API will receive requests and behave accordingly. Such as getting data with a GET requests, and making a new entry with a POST request. But when it came it finding out what a backend is, I get vague answers, that don't really answer my question.

And what is a backend web API? Is it just a combination of the two?

Comment: As applied to web, backend is the server side code, as opposed to the client side code (frontend). If your web API is on the server and does something upon receiving a request from your client side code, it is a backend component. Most of the time it is unhelpful to specify that a web API is backend because really they all are. If all you have is the server-side API, without any client (the frontend), then you may argue that the word "backend" should not be applied because there is no frontend to oppose it to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The term "backend" is quite lose, and can mean many different things -- hence the vague answers you've encountered.

Often, an API is considered a backend "component". And, for instance, a database can also be treated as another backend component.

The APIs you are likely referring to here are web APIs, so could be considered as backend components.

But even the term "API" can mean multiple different things, beyond the web interpretation often encountered. For instance, software libraries are considered APIs, or even the interface an operating system provides to applications is considered an API.